# Reduced relative clause with "ing"

Tags: relative-clauses, infinitive-vs-gerund

I have the following construction,

> A context variable refers to a subset of the DOM tree **nodes which
>   represent** a context.

I doubt if I should say

> A context variable refers to a subset of the DOM tree **nodes
>   representing** a context.

Or for

> ....another anchor which shares the same ancestor
>
> ...another anchor sharing the same ancestor

Are they both correct? In fact I don't know when to use **ing** in relative clause.

The examples of [this source](http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/reduced_relative_clauses.html) are in present continues  form but examples of [this one](http://www.englishgrammar.org/reduced-relative-clauses/) include present form too.

Can I always  use the reduced relative clause with "ing" in present or present continues cases? or it is just for present continues? or for special cases of present? I got confused!

Comment: Actually you don't have present progressive (i.e. continuous) in any of these sentences. The first one is a [reduced relative clause](http://www.englishgrammar.org/reduced-relative-clauses/), it uses a non-finite -ing form (a present participle). Present progressive has to contain the verb *to be* (adequately inflected) so that wouldn't be a non-finite verb form any more.

Comment: @Lucky There is no first or second sentence, they are both one sentence. you mean the first option is correct and a reduced relative clause for the second option?

Comment: Well the first option is a sentence and the second one is also a sentence, they are just very similar and mean the same thing :-). Both of those are correct and the first one contains a reduced relative clause: "representing a context". The way both relative clauses are written they refer to *tree nodes* not a context variable.

Comment: My poor grammar says that you need a comma before your which - 'nodes, which represent a context.'  Or to use 'that' in place of 'which', but honestly, they both read very well as-is.

Answer (score 3):

It is always possible to replace a defining relative clause by a participle construction which is shorter.
Longman English Grammar 1.58.6 (present participle) and 1.62.3 (past participle).

Comment: It is not always possible: see http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49042/reduced-relative-clauses-with-non-progressive-verbs where the use of *liking* sounds terrible in standard English,